# Overloading a function with a function from another class

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a `BinaryMemoryReader` class that has a function defined like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline void read(T **data) {
    *data = (T*)&stream[position];
    position += sizeof(T);
}
```

It handles most of the standard types from a stream in memory.

The custom complex types have read functions of their own, such as:

```
void AnotherClass::read(BinaryMemoryReader *const reader)
{
    reader->read<bool>(&num);
    reader->read<short>(&count);
}
```

What I'd like to is write the code that would, when I write

```
reader->read<AnotherClass>(&var);
```

would call the second function. It would mean that `AnotherClass`s read function would overload the `BinaryMemoryReader`s read function for that particular type.

It would allow me to write a much more cleaner code.

**EDIT:**
The general idea is this:

1. Have a central `BinaryMemoryReader` class.
2. Have a generic read function within it to deal with the standard types.
3. Have the syntax to call it be `bmr->read<int>(&intVar);`
4. Have specialized read functions defined in their own classes.
5. Most importantly, the syntax to call them would be `bmr->read<customType>(&customTypeVar);`

That way the specific read functions would be associated with their own classes, but would be able to be called from the `BinaryMemoryReader`.

Comment: Google "C++ template specialization".

Comment: Note that each of the additional reader functions are defined in their own classes, not in the `BinaryMemoryReader`.

Comment: Why not making a free template function, that takes a `BinaryMemoryReader` parameter and a `T`? This one could be easily specialized in any other class module.

Comment: It should be possible I think to use ADL select the best overload if you a `read` function in the global namespace, but I'm not sure how to achieve this in your case with pointers and such.

Comment: What do you mean by free? Where do I define it? Could I call with a reference to the `BinaryMemoryReader` class?

Would there be a way to have the same call for the standard types and the custom types?

Comment: @Karlovsky120 _free_ means it is declared and defined without any class. Either in the global namespace, or one of your choice.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 BTW, I believe the `T**` double pointer is wrong there. You should either use `T&` or `T*` to provided a simple reference. You would never hand out pointers from that function.

Comment: I need to change where the pointer is pointing, meaning I need to change the pointer, meaning I need the pointer to the pointer.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 _"I need to change where the pointer is pointing"_ That won't work for pointers to member variables anyways, and also your example code doesn't change the pointer. It looked you wanted to copy the contents there.

Comment: No, I have a long array of characters that represent the data, I just need the pointers to point to data that they represent. I'm guessing that's way faster than `memcpy`.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 _" I'm guessing that's way faster than memcpy"_ It simply won't work though.

Comment: But it already is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment I would use the following approach:

1. Have a templated free function

   ```
   template <typename T>
   void read(BinaryMemoryReader& bmr, T& data) {
       bmr.read(&data);
   }
   ```
2. Specialize that function for each of the types you want to handle

   ```
   class AnotherClass {
        template <typename T>
        friend void read(BinaryMemoryReader& bmr, T &data);

        bool num;
        short count;
    };

    template <>
    void read(BinaryMemoryReader& bmr, AnotherClass &data) {
        bmr.read<bool>(&(data.datanum));
        bmr.read<short>(&(data.count));
    };
   ```
3. Call it like

   ```
    BinaryMemoryReader bmr;
    AnotherType at;
    read(bmr,at);
   ```

That technique is used for instance with the *c++ standard I/O library* and overloads provided for the

```
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&);
 std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, T&);
```

functions.

---

Alternatively you could do that specialization for the `BinaryMemoryReader::read()` function. But `BinaryMemoryReader` must be `friend` of all class specializations.

Comment: I dislike doing this in the global namespace. Is there on way to limit this to the `BinaryMemoryReader` class and the types that implement the specific readers? Even if it means writing a bit more of the boilerplate code?

Comment: @Karlovsky120 Sure, you should do that using a specific namespace. Specializing the `BinaryMemoryReader::read()` function would work as well IMO.

Comment: What I mean is that I dislike doing this outside of the classes. While keeping the code in the other class? I'm not sure how to use delegates, but could they be implemented here?